# ssh port issue due to firewall restriction on google compute engine

Tags: ssh, port, firewall

i have changed my ssh default port from 22 to 3322 and than restart ssh service. Situation is my internet was disconnected before i have allowed 3322 port to linux (cent os 7) firewall service. firewall service automatic start is enabled. now how can i access to ssh?. is there any  way? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GCE you can connect to VMs console and then reconfigure the server without having SSH access to it.

1. go to VM Instances page in GCP GUI
2. find your instance, click on it and stay in Details tab
3. 'Connect to serial console' button is what you are looking for. In some cases it can be greyed out so you have to click 'Edit' button and check 'Enable connecting to serial ports'

Comment: Thank you boss. you've saved me. thanks a lot. Its working.